# Missing applets 18.04 Gnome

Tags: 18.04, indicator, gnome-shell, panel

I was messing about with Gnome Fallback/Flashback, it's fun but not what I wanted so I swapped back to Default Ubuntu Gnome Desktop. The stuff I have running no longer appears up in the top panel. I would normally see Variety, Steam, PIA and Insync up in the top right next to the regular applets. These programs are still running but they are not showing up in the panel.

Images to show what I'm talking about

[image]

[image]

Also asked on the Ubuntu forum here https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2403720

Answer (score 2):

In Gnome Tweaks, not installed by default, check whether the extension "Ubuntu appindicators" is enabled. This extension ensures that tray icons are incorporated in the top bar. Depending, it may be advised to restart gnome shell by logging out then back in, or, if you are running on Xorg, by hitting <kbd>Alt+F2</kbd> then <kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: The Ubuntu Appindicators extension has been replaced with "AppIndicator and KStatusNotifierItem Support": https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/615/appindicator-support/
Tested and works great with GNOME Classic on Ubuntu 18.04